# Inserir elementos utilizando o insertBefore do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando realizar uma operação de inserção em meu código JavaScript, mas estou com algumas dificuldade na utilização da função insertBefore.

Primeiro estou criando um elemento do tipo "ul" e realizando a inserção dele dessa maneira:

```
  var novaLista = document.createElement("ul");
  novaLista.setAttribute("class", "itens1 estilo-itens");

  var div = document.getElementById("lista");
  div.insertBefore(novaLista, div.childNodes[0]);
```

Agora estou tentando inserir alguns elementos do tipo "li" nesse elemento criado anteriormente, realizando o seguinte código:

```
  var elemento = document.createElement("li");
  elemento.setAttribute("class", "item");
  var textoElemento = document.createTextNode("elemento");
  elemento.appendChild(textoElemento);

  var list = document.getElementsByClassName('itens1');
  list.insertBefore(elemento, list.childNodes[0]);
```

Mas o seguinte erro é retornado:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Quando realizo o debugging do código percebo que o erro acontece quando estou tentando adicionar o elemento do tipo "li", mas especificamente na linha do insertBefore. Lendo a documentação disponível [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) eu precisaria de uma referencia dentro do elemento "ul" o que na ocasião eu não tenho, teria alguma outra maneira de adicionar esse elemento "li"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função **getElementsByClassName** retorna uma lista de elementos que possuem determinada classe.

Então para seu código funcionar você deve especificar o índice do elemento, como nesse cenário existe apenas um elemento com essa classe, você deve usar o primeiro item da lista:

```
list[0].insertBefore(elemento, list[0].childNodes[0]);
```

**Exemplo Funcional:**

```js
 var novaLista = document.createElement("ul");
 novaLista.setAttribute("class", "itens1 estilo-itens");

 var div = document.getElementById("lista");
 div.insertBefore(novaLista, div.childNodes[0]);

 var elemento = document.createElement("li");
 elemento.setAttribute("class", "item");
 var textoElemento = document.createTextNode("elemento");
 elemento.appendChild(textoElemento);

 var list = document.getElementsByClassName('itens1');
 list[0].insertBefore(elemento, list[0].childNodes[0]);
```

```html
<div id="lista">

</div>
```